# Tabular Model in Azure Portal Won't Open in Visual Studios

Tags: visual-studio, azure, powerbi, tabular, azure-analysis-services

I have a Tabular model in Azure Analysis Services that I created by importing a .pbix. It loaded the model perfectly, but when I try to open the model in Visual Studio nothing happens. When I click on Open in Excel it creates a .odc file and when I click on Open in Power BI it creates a .pbix file. You can see below the options:

Screenshot:
[image]

I would like to open it in Visual Studios. Has anyone else ran into this problem or does anyone else have a solution?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like the *Open in Visual Studio* button is now working. The next day, it now downloads a .zip file that contains a .SMPROJ file and a .BIM file. Not sure why it wasn't working yesterday, maybe the model needs some time after it is created to be able to be loaded into Visual Studios. If anybody knows why, then post, to help anyone else in the future.

Thanks